# neural network - Predict MNIST digits only with one neuron in the output layer

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, mnist

Is it possible to create a neural network where we have one neuron in the output layer which can directly predict digit from NMIST dataset after trainining. eg, if we give digit 3 as input, the output layer neuron should give output value close to 3.

Note: There might be any number of neurons with any number of hidden layers.

Thanks in advance.

This is what I have tried using Tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from mnist import MNIST
import numpy as np


inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 784))
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 1))

logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 1)
loss = 9.0 * tf.sigmoid(logits) - labels # As we want predicted value in [0 - 9]

train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  mnist = MNIST()
  for i in range(100001):
    data, label =  mnist.get_train_data()
    lab = np.zeros((1,1), np.float32)
    lab[0][0] = label
    _, _loss, _logits= sess.run([train_op, loss, logits], feed_dict={inputs: np.reshape(data, (1, 784)), labels: lab})
    if i%5000 == 0:
      print("Step: %d Loss: %6f <== logits %s, Actual: %6f" % (i, _loss, str(_logits),  label))



Step: 0 Loss: -0.436195 <== logits [[ 0.02835961]], Actual: 5.000000
Step: 5000 Loss: -6.999933 <== logits [[-11.80182171]], Actual: 7.000000
Step: 10000 Loss: -2.999990 <== logits [[-13.7065649]], Actual: 3.000000
Step: 15000 Loss: -4.999864 <== logits [[-11.09644413]], Actual: 5.000000
Step: 20000 Loss: -5.000000 <== logits [[-17.01583481]], Actual: 5.000000
Step: 25000 Loss: -2.999971 <== logits [[-12.66251564]], Actual: 3.000000
Step: 30000 Loss: -2.999927 <== logits [[-11.72266102]], Actual: 3.000000
Step: 35000 Loss: -0.999898 <== logits [[-11.38729763]], Actual: 1.000000
Step: 40000 Loss: -7.000000 <== logits [[-17.59585381]], Actual: 7.000000
Step: 45000 Loss: -3.000000 <== logits [[-17.72655296]], Actual: 3.000000
Step: 50000 Loss: -5.000000 <== logits [[-16.65830421]], Actual: 5.000000
Step: 55000 Loss: -6.999999 <== logits [[-15.97771645]], Actual: 7.000000
Step: 60000 Loss: -3.000000 <== logits [[-17.10641289]], Actual: 3.000000
Step: 65000 Loss: -4.999984 <== logits [[-13.26896667]], Actual: 5.000000
Step: 70000 Loss: -5.000000 <== logits [[-19.57778549]], Actual: 5.000000
Step: 75000 Loss: -2.999995 <== logits [[-14.30502892]], Actual: 3.000000
Step: 80000 Loss: -2.999982 <== logits [[-13.13857365]], Actual: 3.000000
Step: 85000 Loss: -0.999971 <== logits [[-12.63682747]], Actual: 1.000000
Step: 90000 Loss: -7.000000 <== logits [[-19.08620071]], Actual: 7.000000
Step: 95000 Loss: -3.000000 <== logits [[-19.23719406]], Actual: 3.000000
Step: 100000 Loss: -5.000000 <== logits [[-17.85402298]], Actual: 5.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible of course, but it is not a good idea. Digit recognition is a classification problem. By only using a single output neuron you are proposing to treat it as a regression problem. The implicit assumption you are making is that numbers that are close to each other numerically also *look* similar. This is obviously not the case. For instance, `3` and `5` look more similar than `3` and `4` as the bottom part is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Geerth, but want to add just one bit. Indeed, it's real if you use regression model instead of classification. But regression models assume that your input is ordered (you can use any order, for example 1,2,3.... or 1,3,2,5,4 or any other and your model will have different parameters).
["Introduction to Statistical Learning"](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) book has some good ideas about it (and it's free).